# Creating a directory and inserting another director inside that directory in PHP

Tags: php, directory

I have a directory on my root called profiles.

I want to add another dir into that and another inside that something like this

profiles > jack > user_images

```
$username_entry = "jack";
$user_image_dir = "user_images";

mkdir(profiles."/".$username_entry, 0777, true);
mkdir(profiles."/".$username_entry."/".$user_image_dir, 0777, true);
```

But i dont think this is the correct way to do it.

Can anyone help me do this the correct way.

Comment: Is `profiles` a constant? Where is it defined ? And what should be wrong with your code?

Comment: it is not defined. It is a permanent directory.

Comment: Why do you tread it as constant? Then put it in quotes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, you can also check if the directory does not exist before creating it:

```
if (!file_exists("profiles/".$username_entry)) {
       mkdir("profiles/".$username_entry, 0777, true);
```

}

**EDIT:**
To create the directory in the root, we can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`:

```
  if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/profiles/".$username_entry))  
    {
       mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/profiles/".$username_entry, 0777, true);
    }
```

Comment: It isn't creating the directorys though. Im running that script by itself on a local server. So that should work?

Comment: yes, the problem could be `profiles`, are you sure it has something? @SpringheeledJack

Comment: running it without profiles andjust the variables doesnt seem to work either though.

Comment: @SpringheeledJack i edited my answer to include `profiles` as a string, please make that change and try again

Comment: It's not creating anything. I have a profiles in my root.

Comment: That works, but its creating the folders in the current folder and not on the root...

Comment: @SpringheeledJack add a slash infront of `profiles` like this `"/profiles/".$username_entry`, in those two lines

Comment: @SpringheeledJack i have updated my answer to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get the root

Comment: mkdir("/profiles/".$username_entry."/".$user_image_dir, 0777, true);

This is making the folders the otherway round somehow.

so $user_image_dir contains $username_entry

Comment: do you need to swap the variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76640/discussion-between-springheeled-jack-and-luthando-loot).

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing your script from root directory this one line should work as intended:

```
mkdir("/profiles/".$username_entry."/".$user_image_dir, 0777, true);
```

Comment: Will that create both directorys ($username_entry & $user_image_dir)?

Comment: If last parameter is set to TRUE, mkdir will create every directory that doesn't exist yet. Check here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: It hasnt solved the problem though. It is still not creating the directorys.

Comment: what if im not executing from the root?

Comment: Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/welcometowarwick/scripts/php/playground.php on line 9

if i remove the first / it works but created in the scripts/php folder...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76707/discussion-between-springheeled-jack-and-reversal).